# Find and count Emails in a .txt file

Tags: python-3.x, parsing

The goal of this code is in the title but to only find emails that start with "From ". Something to note my professor required me to use three variables. The .txt file we are using [mbox.txt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w6fb681f6ylhgbq/mbox.txt?dl=0) My code:

```
import time

try:
     fh = open('mbox.txt')
except IOError:
     print('Yo, we aint find mbox.txt')
     print("The program will now self-destruct")
     time.sleep(10)
     quit()


email1 = input('First email: ')
email2 = input('Second email: ')
email3 = input('Third email: ')
counter1 = 0
counter2 = 0
counter3 = 0
for line in fh:
     nline = line.rstrip()
     if not line.startswith('From '): continue
     if line.find(email1):
         counter1 += 1
     elif line.find(email2):
         counter2 += 1
     elif line.find(email3):
         counter3 += 1
print('\nFirst email:', email1, '=', counter1)
print('Second email:', email2, '=', counter2)
print('Third email:', email3, '=', counter3)
```

The input and output:

```
In [1];First email: gjthomas@iupui.edu

   ...;Second email: lance@indiana.edu

   ...;Third email: nuno@ufp.pt

Output: First email: gjthomas@iupui.edu = 1797
Output: Second email: lance@indiana.edu = 0
Output: Third email: nuno@ufp.pt = 0
```

So my questions is; Why does the first email always print the same number 1797 (where is that coming from)? I believe the problem is the counters are not sticking so how do i keep track of the counters while they are counting?

Comment: What are the contents of `mbox.txt`?

Comment: Sorry, I added it to the post. https://www.dropbox.com/s/w6fb681f6ylhgbq/mbox.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR; The `1797` value comes from the count of all lines that start with `From`.

Many possible solutions, but the easiest may be to use [`str.count(substring)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.count):

```
for line in fh:
    nline = line.rstrip()
    counter1 += line.count(email1)
    counter2 += line.count(email2)
    counter3 += line.count(email3)

print('\nFirst email:', email1, '=', counter1)
print('Second email:', email2, '=', counter2)
print('Third email:', email3, '=', counter3)
```

outputs:

```
First email: gjthomas@iupui.edu = 184
Second email: lance@indiana.edu = 33
Third email: nuno@ufp.pt = 114
```

---

Explanation: Where is the `1797` value coming from?

`line.find('gjthomas@iupui.edu')` returns the position (string index) of the found string , and `-1` if the string is not found. So it's always returning `-1` if `'gjthomas@iupui.edu'` is not found, and `5` in this case if it *is* found:

```
'From gjthomas@iupui.edu Tue Oct 23 09:23:04 2007\n'
0^^^^^^
1_|||||
2__||||
3___|||
4____||
5_____| starting index of the string is found
```

The tricky part now is that python's [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) states:

> By default, an object is considered true unless its class defines either a `__bool__()` method that returns False or a `__len__()` method that returns zero, when called with the object.

So for each line that *does* start with `From`, then the next line gets evaluated:

```
if line.find(email1): # both cases if `-1` if `5` evaluate to Truthy value
    counter1 += 1
```

so basically any line that starts with `From` *will* increment the first counter, `counter1`, and thus the subsequent `elif`'s do not get checked nor their counters get incremented.